# Python script errors out when run from mac cron job but not from mac terminal

Tags: python, macos, character-encoding, cron

I have a `Python v3.6` script which reads from database which has some data with Chinese characters. This script gives error when I schedule it to run from Mac Cron Job; however executes fine when run from my Mac's Terminal.

Any idea, if we need to enable some language pack or something when we run script from Cron job?

**Crontab command**:

```
#*/2 * * * * /usr/local/bin/python3 /Users/admin/Documents/Scripts/wht/gbi.py >> test.txt
```

Comment: Update the question with the error

Comment: Maybe it is using python 2.x rather than 3.6

Comment: I have given the path till python 3 in my cron job command as well

Comment: Can you post the errors thrown when run as cron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's encode those characters. Example:

**DON'T use them directly** in source code:

```
 SPECIAL_CHARS = u"aAàÀảẢãÃáÁạẠăĂằẰẳẲẵẴắẮặẶâÂầẦẩẨẫẪấẤậẬ"
```

Let's use:

```
 SPECIAL_CHARS = u'aA\xe0\xc0\u1ea3\u1ea2\xe3\xc3\xe1\xc1\u1ea1\u1ea0\u0103\u0102\u1eb1\u1eb0\u1eb3\u1eb2\u1eb5\u1eb4\u1eaf\u1eae\u1eb7\u1eb6\xe2\xc2\u1ea7\u1ea6\u1ea9\u1ea8\u1eab\u1eaa\u1ea5\u1ea4\u1ead\u1eac'
```

You can encode string to **utf-8** and use it normally:

```
 encoded_str = SPECIAL_CHARS.encode('utf-8')

 print(type(encoded_str))
 print(encoded_str)
```

Comment: Oh, I get those from database and don't know before hand what all characters will be there. Is there any API available for doing this? [I am new to Python :)]